# bootstrap datepicker sandbox-container giving blank div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap) datepicker but when I clicked on the input, it gives me a blank div like this
[image]

where is a snippet:

```js
$('#sandbox-container input').datepicker({
  format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
  weekStart: 1,
  autoclose: true,
  todayHighlight: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">

<div class="col-md-12">
  <h4>Date Range:</h4>
  <div class='col-sm-4' id="sandbox-container">
    From:
    <input type="text" id="fromdate" style="padding-left: 40px;"><span style="right: 200px; top: 0px; border-right: 1px solid #ccc; padding-right: 8px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </div>
  <div class='col-sm-4' id="sandbox-container">
    To:
    <input type="text" id="todate" style="padding-left: 40px;"><span style="right: 200px; top: 0px; border-right: 1px solid #ccc; padding-right: 8px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

it worked great in the snippet!!!! but in my project doesn't work!!!!

Comment: Did you check the console for errors?

Comment: yes, and no errors there, but I've this **DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: vendors/bootstrap-select/bootstrap-select.js.map** and I don't think that "bootstrap-select" will affect "bootstrap-datepicker"

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Well, without looking at the actual code it will be hard o help. Try to create a working snippet that shows the problem.

Comment: I fixed **DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: vendors/bootstrap-select/bootstrap-select.js.map** and nothing happens to the date-picker.. anyways, I'll try to create a snippet

Comment: It appears to be working when I run the code snippet in page.  If bootstrap-select is causing issues, you could try my alternative method for bootstrap select box:   https://codepen.io/btn-ninja/pen/eWYbqB

Comment: Sorry, it my mistake. It was a CSS issue.. thanks all for your support